How to prevent or work around SwiftUI TabView's selection getting out of sync with the displayed tab?
I find that that on iOS, e.g. on 17.2, that if a TabView's selection is set and then set again before the tab swipe animation completes, then the selection state gets out of sync with the tab that's shown.
In this example, if you tap "Go to tab 2" twice quickly, before the animation to tab 2 completes, then the animation to tab 2 is canceled, the screen stays on tab 1, but the selection state value stays as 2.
I found a workaround which I coded on tab 2, which is to check if the state value is already the new value, and reset it to another value before setting it to the desired value. However is there a better workaround so that the selection state value is always the actual tab that is shown? Thank you
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var activeTab = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $activeTab) {
            VStack {
                Text("Tab 1")
                Button {
                    withAnimation {
                        activeTab = 2
                    }
                } label: {
                    Label("Go to tab 2", systemImage: "arrow.right")
                }
            }
            .tag(1)

            VStack {
                Text("Tab 2")
                Button {
                    if activeTab == 1 {
                        activeTab = 2
                    }

                    withAnimation {
                        activeTab = 1
                    }
                } label: {
                    Label("Go to tab 1", systemImage: "arrow.left")
                }
            }
            .tag(2)
        }
        .tabViewStyle(.page)
        .indexViewStyle(.page(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
    }
}

@main
struct TestTabViewApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}


Some would argue this is the flaw in SwiftUIs state driven design, some interactions like swipes are not stateful

This bit (on your second Button) looks odd:
                if activeTab == 1 {
                    activeTab = 2
                }

You don't have a parallel closure on the first Button. So sometimes you're (potentially) changing state during ContentView evaluation, and sometimes not.
I'm not sure it's a great idea to add your own animation on top of whatever TabView is doing to transition.

Hi, that code in the button action on tab 2 is the workaround for tabview not keeping state consisten with the ui. Also i am not adding my own animation- without that code the page view transition doesn’t animate. Thank you
